# How to get the current date and time in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format in ksh88?

Tags: ksh, date

My requirement is to get difference of 2 timestamps in hours.

As the date diff option is taking long for me to figure out I am trying to convert both dates in to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format and find the number difference. So I need to get the current date and time in the same format.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I believe this is the command you need:

```
date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
```

Comment: oh thanks !! i did try this but had made a typo err. thank you

Comment: For ISO 8601 date format use: `date '+%Y-%m-%d'`